# Three Fathers Gathered

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Three Fathers gathered
>   Cross a score minus two
>
> The Assembled Ones gathered
>   Cross a score plus five
>
> To rebut the Rebuttals
>   Cross five score minus five
>
> Handed down their Decrees
>   Cross a score minus three

Hint:

> The first father gathered,
>  Third of his name.
>  The second fathered gathered,
>  Third of his name.
>  The third father gathered,
>  Fourth of his name.

Comment: Four score cross seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new puzzle...

Comment: -*A*braham *Vi*ncoln

Comment: What form is the answer supposed to be in?

Comment: The riddle describes a person, place, or thing.

Comment: Well, I know who, what, where and when, but I'm currently missing the significance of the cross/score lines...

Comment: (_Maybe_ I understand "five score minus five" but I suspect not.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about

> the [Council of Trent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Trent)

which was called by

> Popes Paul III, Julius III, and Pius IV (though none of them actually attended the council)

as per the hint.

```
Three Fathers gathered
Cross a score minus two
```

> The "three Fathers" are the popes mentioned above. ("Pope" *means* "father".) Maybe "a score minus two" = 18 = the number of years the Council sat for?

```
The Assembled Ones gathered
Cross a score plus five
```

> I'm not sure *exactly* why "the Assembled Ones". I want it to be related to words like "synod" (synodos = travelling together = assembling), "congregation" (con, together, + gregare, to assemble), etc., but if there's a really specific reference I'm not seeing it. Maybe "a score plus five" = 25 = the number of sessions of the Council? [EDITED to add:] OP explains in comments that the specific word he had in mind was Gk "ekklesia", originally meaning a gathering or civic assembly, adopted as meaning "church", origin of words like "ecclesiastical".

```
To rebut the Rebuttals
Cross five score minus five
```

> The Council of Trent was all about responding to the Reformation: rebutting the Rebuttals. Maybe "five score minus five" = 95, the number of Luther's *theses*. (Confession: an earlier version of this answer claimed that five score minus five = 45, because I am an idiot.)

```
Handed down their Decrees
Cross a score minus three
```

> Like many other ecumenical councils, it issued a bunch of decrees. Maybe "a score minus three" = 17 = the number of dogmatic decrees issued by the Council?

Comment: r13 Svir fpber zvahf svir vf avargl svir. [Gur Nffrzoyrq Barf](https://biblehub.com/greek/1577.htm)

Comment: Ugh, can't count. I did wonder specifically about the word you link to but surely its actual etymology is different ("called out" or something like that). On further investigation, there seems to be a little dispute about that, and at any rate its original meaning does have to do with assemblies.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot13(Avargl-svir gurfr ortna gur Cebgrfgnag ersbezngvba, juvpu yrq gb lbhe nafjre.) , perhaps?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Fixed the 45/95 error (and added the obvious referent) and added a bit about the Assembled Ones.

Comment: @KradCigol Yes, indeed. [EDITED to add:] The reason I didn't have that in was that I miscalculated "five score minus five" :-).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Incidentally, I was expecting _something_ along these lines from when the puzzle was first posted, but the "rebutting the Rebuttals" bit got me hung up on the rot13(flabq bs Qbeg) with its rot13(erohggnyf gb gur fb-pnyyrq Erzbafgenaprf).